# Why isn't `nslookup` able to resolve an A record in route53, when I specifically use a nameserver from my hosted zone?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, dig, nslookup

I'm trying to host a static website in s3. I have a domain registered with namecheap, and it is pointing at route53 nameservers. This part seems to be working correctly based on `dig`:

```
dig getgargoyle.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> getgargoyle.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47011
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;getgargoyle.com.       IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
getgargoyle.com.    900 IN  SOA ns-1814.awsdns-34.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 16 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Oct 28 14:21:37 EDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 128
```

From that, it seems like it is using the correct nameserver. But when I try to nslookup the domain, I get nothing:

```
nslookup getgargoyle.com
Server:     1.1.1.1
Address:    1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find getgargoyle.com: No answer
```

I get the same problem even when I point nslookup at one of the route53 nameservers:

```
nslookup getgargoyle.com ns-1814.awsdns-34.co.uk
Server:     ns-1814.awsdns-34.co.uk
Address:    205.251.199.22#53

*** Can't find getgargoyle.com: No answer
```

I have the A record created in route53 pointing to the s3 bucket. For example here is the relevant output of `aws route53 list-resource-record-sets`:

```
{
  "Name": "getgargoyle.com.",
  "Type": "A",
  "AliasTarget": {
    "HostedZoneId": "Z3AQBSTGFYJSTF",
    "DNSName": "getgargoyle.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.",
    "EvaluateTargetHealth": false
   }
}
```

I am able to navigate to the site using the s3 domain (which is the value of the A record). What am I missing here?

[Here is the namecheap name server config for the domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1zux.png)

[Here is the route53 hosted zone details showing the nameservers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMvZk.png)

Comment: Double check that the name servers in NameCheap match the name servers at the top of the Route53 console page for the hosted zone. They should match the NS record in the hosted zone, but if they don't you want to make sure all 3 are the same. Also may want to look at using CloudFront in front of S3. It supports TLS connections (HTTPS) and does not really add a lot of cost, if any. Use ACM for certs

Comment: Thanks Tim - I do indeed want to use cloudfront here. I added a screenshot to show that the nameservers configured in namecheap match the route53 hosted zone. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SF :) You don't have a DNS record published, according to MXToolbox (see picture below). The general steps you need to follow for registering a domain and making it available on AWS are below.

I haven't done the S3 domain thing for a while so I can't remember how it changes things, but I suspect it adds steps rather than changing these steps.

- Register your domain (looks like that's done)
- Create a Route53 hosted zone (if you're using AWS DNS)
- Configure your domain registrar to point to the Route53 domain servers it gives you when you created the hosted zone

[image: MXToolbox Record]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim! Unfortunately I've done all of those things already :( I added a screenshot of the route53 hosted zone details to show that the nameservers are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the problem was the trailing `.`'s after the nameservers in namecheap. Removing those seems to have resolved the problem.

Comment: Interesting. A fully formed domain has a "dot" at the end, called an "absolute fully formed domain" apparently. Not accepting this is not good by NameCheap. RFC 1034.